# Can anyone assist with the interpretation of the symbol that is being depicted in this calligraphy artwork?

Tags: meaning, characters, character-identification, seal

**This is a framed scroll painting that was executed by the artist "TIESHENG" as indicated in the oval shaped seal on the lower left. It measures 36 x 28 inches. The two seals on the right refer to principles of Buddhist philosophy. However the symbol depicted in the painting has me puzzled.[image]

Comment: I can't make all of it, but if this is something about Buddha, maybe the top right is 心, there is a 尘 in the left part.

Comment: I pretty much have the seals and the script figured  out.  It's the representation and meaning of the artwork itself that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: what is the exact Chinese word of the script?

Comment: In response to Archeosudoerus.

Comment: "Tiesheng ; Three Minds ; On The 6th month of the year xinwei" is the interpretation of the script.

Comment: There are countless such paintings, and after many people had made this kind of paintings, no one can guess except himself. This painting is extremely ordinary and of little value. You should look carefully at the red seal, which indicates the value of the painting. If it is an ordinary seal, it is a make-up seal.